# unable to lock a file in RHEL6.4

Tags: bitbucket, rhel, rhel7, rhel6

Trying to lock a file in RHEL but seeing following issue

**Stopped the services**

`service rpcbind stop
service nfslock stop
rm -rf /var/lib/nfs/statd/sm/*
rm -rf /var/lib/nfs/statd/sm.bak/*
service rpcbind start
service nfslock start`

After this I'm using C program mentioned in https://community.microfocus.com/microfocus/cobol/net_express__server_express/w/knowledge_base/6215/c-program-to-validate-nfs-locking-ability
to :-

•   Open File(Create)

•   Lock File

•   Close File

But seeing below errors
[root@mywebappsserver shared]$ ./nfs_lock
FATAL ERROR: Could not lock file

Even after restarting rpcbind  and nfslock not seeing any entry under 
`# ls -l /var/lib/nfs/statd/sm/`

Need your help in same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it after changing /var/lib permissions

Before:-

## ls -ld lib

drwx------. 34 root root 4096 Jul  7 08:32 lib
After:-

## ls -ld lib

drwxr-xr-x. 34 root root 4096 Jul  7 08:32 lib